# I am not sure why the code isn't running, it throws an error while compiling saying it is unable to locate PrintArray()

Tags: c++

```
int main()
{
    const char arr[][5] = {{ 'H','u','g','o','\0' },{'h','i'}};
    printArray(arr, 2, 5);

}

void printArray(const char arr[], int size)

{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void printArray(const char arr[][SIZE], int rows, int cols)
{   char temp[cols];

        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {char temp[cols];
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            {
                temp[j]=arr[i][j];
            }
            printArray(temp,cols);

        }

}
```

The code is meant to print the double dimensional array line by line. And it's supposed to overload `printArray();`

Not sure why it does not work, everything seems to be fine.

> error message: No matching function for call to 'printArray' at this line printArray(arr, 2, 5);

Comment: Define *does not work*

Comment: i added the error message

Comment: `printArray()` needs to be declared before (i.e. above) the point where it is used.   If it is declared before, then optionally it can be defined afterward (e.g. in your case, below `main()`).     If you want to use both overloads of `printArray()` then BOTH need to be declared before their first usage.

Answer (score 0):

You might be facing a behaviour of C++ compiler, namely order of declaration.
Basically, your `main()` function try to call to yet undefined `printArray` function. By reordering the definition, the function call will work: https://onlinegdb.com/r1jMt9d0r.

```
void printArray(const char arr[], int size)
{
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void printArray(const char arr[][SIZE], int rows, int cols)
{   char temp[cols];

        for(int i=0;i<rows;i++)
        {char temp[cols];
            for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
            {
                temp[j]=arr[i][j];
            }
            printArray(temp,cols);

        }

}

int main()
{
    const char arr[][5] = {{ 'H','u','g','o','\0' },{'h','i'}};
    printArray(arr, 2, 5);

}
```

This question actually have been asked, but you might not able to search the solution.

Comment: Thats the thing, if i try and call Printarray(single dimensional array, it works) so I was confused

Comment: Have you tried the linked sandbox? Can you tweak the code and edit your question to includes the one that failed?

Comment: I tried it, the problem is I think the compiler for some reason isn’t recognising the overloaded function, am I passing the right arguments in?

Comment: Then, please provide your compile command and compiler version in the question. Someone might be able to reproduce and propose some solution for you.

Comment: That depends on what `SIZE` is.  And that is not shown by the OP.

Comment: @user92382 Ah yes, that might be true too. Your passed argument size and `SIZE` in signature of `printArray` possibly do not match.